# How to change upper panel cinnamon

Tags: cinnamon

I would like to change the size of the upper panel on firefox (where u can close the window) with cinnamon theme, i tried everything without success.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about reducing the font size?

Answer (score 0):

A limited option solution, but you can try this Firefox addon:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hide-caption-titlebar-plus-sma/